# HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, timeout

I just want to ask if theres a way to increase the executionTimeOut of a particular page? and not the whole application?

```
<configuration>    
  <system.web>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="4096" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Page.Server.ScriptTimeout = 90;
```

Or

[use location element in config file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
<configuration>
  <location path="UploadPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="4096" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

See [To Increase Request Timeout only on particular Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127756/to-increase-request-timeout-only-on-particular-web-page) and [Increase ASP.Net timeout on a per page level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108678/increase-asp-net-timeout-on-a-per-page-level)

Answer (score 0):

put in Web Config File

```
 <location path="Report.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="10240"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```